# How can I send a response that is a block of code in a node request response function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, response

I am trying to have a server side function return a block of code.  For example, I want to send the following back after a request:

```
$('body').css('background-color', 'blue')
```

What I did was wrap this in quotes and have the following response:

```
res.end("$('body').css('background-color', 'blue')");
```

However, as I write many lines code, I want to be able to write it without quotation marks.  How can I store many lines of code in one variable perhaps so that I can write `res.end(codesnippet)`?

Comment: How about just using a .css file for styles and a .js file for javascript on the clientside ?

Comment: I'm trying to send back responses to requests coming in from different websites.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape new lines with a backslash `\`. So you would end each line like this:

```
var codesnippet = "$('body').css('background-color', 'blue')\
                            .css('margin', '10px');"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to create an API: See https://github.com/awatson1978/rest-api

Also look at [`iron:router`](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#server-routing) server side routes for the basics.

Comment: Yes, I do want to create an API and am using server side routes, but am trying to figure out how I can send back pure code in the form of a string as the response rather than executed code in the form of JSON or an object.

Comment: @DavidMckee sorry, perhaps this will help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify